# Replacing Class Names by Strings Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

This is currently what I do

```
var longTextList = this.props.data.map(function(text, index){
                        return <Thumbnail key={index} style={fontSize} ><div style={fontFamily}><img src={text.sprite} />{text.longText} and get {coinName}(s)</div></Thumbnail>;
                      });
```

Since, `return` returns a string, why can't we replace the class name with a user defined string.

For instance `<Thumbnail>` with `<{this.props.type>` where `this.props.type=Thumbnail`.

**EDIT**

I'm calling my class like this

```
<CardView data={actionList} fontSize={fontSize} fontFamily={fontFamily} coinName={coinName} type="Thumbnail"/>
```

where type tells us to render a Thumbnail.

In CardView.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Thumbnail } from 'react-bootstrap';


const CardView = React.createClass({


    render() {
        var fontFamily = this.props.fontFamily;
        var fontSize = this.props.fontSize;
        var coinName = this.props.coinName;
        var Type = this.props.type;
var longTextList = this.props.data.map(function(text, index){
                        return <Type key={index} style={fontSize} ><div style={fontFamily}><img src={text.sprite} />{text.longText} and get {coinName}(s)</div></Thumbnail>;
                      });


        return (
            <div>{longTextList}</div>
            );
    }
});

export default CardView;
```

Facing Error

```
Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <Type>
```

Comment: The error you're getting is because you still have `</Thumbnail>` instead of </Type> in the map function, however, I do not believe fixing this will allow you to do what you want anyway.  See my answer for more.

Comment: Damn! Yes, that was it. Apparently my text editor wasn't on word wrap, and the other tag was out of screen, so forgot about it. Sorry ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace class names by string as long as this string begins with an uppercase letter. It is JSX standard to have the component first letter uppercase. It is useful to make the difference between standard HTML tag and custom tags representing components. Read more on the dot notation: [tags vs react components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components)

As a result, for example, you can use the dot notation: `<MyVar.mytype/>`

If you define the component type dynamically using a text variable `"Tumbnail"`, you have to reference, in a dictionary, the component related to the component type. Otherwise, there is no possible way transpilation will guess which component to use.

You must do:

In a file name `MyComponent.js`:

```
import { Thumbnail } from 'react-bootstrap';
const MyComponents={
  Thumbnail
};
export default MyComponents;
```

In your React Component, import `MyComponent` and:

```
var Type = MyComponents[this.props.type];
return <Type/>;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't get the idea. Could you please explain it a little bit more? What I am getting by your answer is, if i assign `MyVar = this.props.type`, I can then change my `<Thumbnail>` to `<MyVar>` , but it doesn't work

Comment: if, as written in your example, `this.props.type=Thumbnail`, `MyVar = this.props.type` should work. How is defined `this.props.type` in your case?

Comment: Please see Edit.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. Still facing the same error stated in the previous edit.

Comment: In your "edit", you didn't close `Type` at the end. Replace `</Thumbnail>` with `</Type>`

Answer (score 0):

Can you bypass the string and just pass the type as the prop?

```
import { Thumbnail } from 'react-bootstrap';

<CardView data={actionList} fontSize={fontSize} fontFamily={fontFamily} coinName={coinName} type={Thumbnail}/>
```

Now in CardView.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const CardView = React.createClass({

    render() {
        var fontFamily = this.props.fontFamily;
        var fontSize = this.props.fontSize;
        var coinName = this.props.coinName;
        var Type = this.props.type;
        var longTextList = this.props.data.map(function(text, index){
                               return <Type key={index} style={fontSize} ><div style={fontFamily}><img src={text.sprite} />{text.longText} and get {coinName}(s)</div></Type>;
                           });

        return (
            <div>{longTextList}</div>
            );
    }
});

export default CardView;
```